# RDLC report showing left 1.5inch right margin and 2.5 bottom margin

Tags: vb.net, rdlc

I have designed a RDLC report, i have assigned right body size and report size with 0 margins but when i run my report, print layout showing white space at right and bottom of the page and same when i print the report.

I am using Visual Studio 2015.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just adjusted my screen resolution and its all fine now.